# How to pass parameter from controller to model on with method?

Tags: laravel, parameters, model

I have a model,

```
public function feedback($id)
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker', 'feedback', 
                                'feedback_id','worker_id')
                ->where('worker_id',$id);
}
```

I want to pass value to the model from controller,

```
$result = Worker::with('feedback(2)');
$result->some operations after this
```

I want to pass value like this. But it is not working.

I have list of 10 workers (id 1 to 10), if the worker id 7 logged in, I want to display the all the 10 workers and along with worker id 7, I want to display his feedbacks also. it is my requirement.

Comment: What you want to achieve ? please explain ? I mean why you want to do this ?

Comment: its not working.

Comment: The way you are trying to explain is object of class. when you update object of class will not update class.

Comment: I want to display all workers list. If the worker logged in along with the list i want to display the feedbacks belongs to the worker

Comment: @selva I have given the way to get as you want check this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'll be using belongsToMany

```
public function feedback()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker', 'feedback_id')
}
```

And use find() when you want to get a data using id

```
$worker = Worker::find(2);
$worker->feedback();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve like below.

In Model

```
   public function feedback()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker', 'feedback', 'feedback_id', 'worker_id');
   }
```

In Controller

```
 $id = 2;
 $result = Worker::whereHas('feedback',function($q) use($id){
               $q->where('worker_id',$id);
           });
```

Read about `->whereHas` in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: I have list of 10 workers (id 1 to 10), if the worker id 7 logged in, I want to display the 10 workers and on the worker id 7 along with his details i want to display his feedbacks also. it is my requirement @Niklesh Raut can you please help me out

Comment: is your problem solved what you asked in question ?

Comment: Yes my problem is solved and i posted my answer. Thanks for your answer I got idea from your code to find my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't use where function in model relationships..

```
public function feedback()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker', 'feedback_id', 'worker_id');
}
```

In controller

```
 $result = Worker::find(2);
 $worker->feedback();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model

**Worker.php model**

```
public function feedback()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker', 'feedback', 'worker_id','feedback_id');
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
$id = 7;
$result = Worker::with('feedback')->where('id',$id)->first();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result->toArray());
exit;
```

Or in get method

```
$results = Worker::with('feedback')->get();

foreach($results as $result){
    if(!empty($results->feedback)){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result->feedback->toArray());
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody responding my question. I have found my answer. This is my solution and it is worked for me,

```
$id = 7
$result = Worker::with(['feedback' => function($q) use($id){
               $q->where('worker_id',$id);
}]);
```